# Show how many servers bot is in one embed | Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot is on about 20 servers and I'd like to see but I'm having trouble embedding in one embed  not many emeds

Code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'servers',
    description: 'Wyświetla serwery na których jest bot',
    type: 1,
    options: [],


    run: async (client, interaction, guild, args) => {

        const BOT = client.users.cache.get('id')

        if (interaction.user.id != 'id') {
            let embed0 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor('#791616')
                .setTitle('Błąd')
                .setDescription(`You haven't premission`)
                .setFooter({ text: `Błąd - Servers`, iconURL: BOT.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed0] })
            return;
        }

        interaction.reply('WYSYŁANIE W TOKU...')

        client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
            const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`Servers`)
                .setDescription(`Nazwa: ${guild.name} |  ID: ${guild.id} | OWNER <@${guild.ownerId}>`)
                .setFooter({ text: `Servers` })

            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1] })
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14MDg.png)

I want to be able to list all servers in a single embed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bot is in less than 25 servers you can create an embed and add servers as fields:

```js
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Servers');

client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    embed
        .addFields({
            name: guild.name,
            value: `ID: ${guild.id} | OWNER: <@${guild.ownerId}>`
        });
});

interaction.channel.send({
    embeds: [embed]
});
```

Comment: Can I make several pages of the command?
How yes, how?

Comment: You should check "embed paginator" npm module. They can simply do that by providing multiple embeds and using buttons to navigate between them.